# Trying to move a csv file from local file system to hadoop file system

Tags: linux, hadoop

I am trying to copy a csv file from my local file system to hadoop. But I am not able to successfully do it. I am not sure which permissions i need to change. As I understand. hdfs super user does not have access to the `/home/naya/dataFiles/BlackFriday.csv`

```
hdfs dfs -put /home/naya/dataFiles/BlackFriday.csv /tmp
# Error: put: Permission denied: user=naya, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

```
sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -put /home/naya/dataFiles/BlackFriday.csv /tmp
# Error: put: `/home/naya/dataFiles/BlackFriday.csv': No such file or directory
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I want to do it via the command line utility. I can do it via cloudera manager from the hadoop side. But I want to understand whats happening behind the commands

Comment: You can't write to `/tmp` in hdfs. Being root on your local system won't give you permissions to do it either. Start with `hdfs dfs -put /home/naya/dataFiles/BlackFriday.csv BlackFriday.csv` and then look at where that is in hdfs.

Comment: @Elliott Has that changed? Or have I always been in an environment where /tmp has 777 permission?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Could be a group setting. I can't recall writing to `/tmp` in hdfs. That wouldn't be HIPAA.